# UItabBar blocks the bottom content of UIViewController's view?

Tags: swift

I have a UINavigationController embedded in a UITabBarController.  When I push a UIviewController to the stack, the UIviewcontroller's view at the bottom is blocked by the UITabBar at the bottom.  How do I get the view of the UIViewController to be above the tabBar or a sub view to be above the tabBar?

problem:

[image]

I have tried the following layout for a subView but it creates a crash:

```
    view.addSubview(pdfView)
    pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBarController?.tabBar.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

CRash message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x280aa4ac0 "PDFView:0x101641540.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x280aa4b40 "UITabBar:0x101609740.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Comment: You need to make the bottomConstraint related to your view Bottom and then your view should be constrained to bottomSafeAre margin, that should fix your issue

Comment: @ReinierMelian please could you elaborate with some code?Thank you for your patience